# How can I change shape of the input image array as per my trained TensorFlow model input?

Tags: tensorflow, numpy, python-3.x

I have a Tensorflow model weight file that I am using to make the prediction on test images. These test images are in NumPy array format and the shapes of the images are (720, 1280, 3).
I am getting the following error while making the prediction-

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 416, 416, 3), found shape=(1, 720, 1280, 3)
```

When I tried to change the shape like below-

```
image_np.shape=(416,416,3)
```

It is giving me the following error-

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2764800 into shape (416,416,3)
```

I am using Tensorflow 2.x with Python 3.7.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the model expects images of 416 by 416 pixels, whereas you are using larger images. Simply using `reshape` doesn't work since the overall number of pixels is still to high for a 416x416 image (720 * 1280 > 416 * 416). Therefore you have to resize your image first to 416x416 before passing it to your model. You can either directly resize to 416x416 (which would give an image with a different aspect ratio) or resize first but retain the aspect ratio and then pad the image to get to 416x416. You could use the [`resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.resize) function from the `cv2` library to resize an image.

Comment: I understand your point. Since input images are in NumPy format; I tried np.resize(image_np,(416,416,3)) and the error is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

you can use use "change mode" to change the channel into channel first or channel last format.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import  img_to_array
y = np.zeros((len(ids), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.float32)
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(ids), total=len(ids)):
    # Load images
    img = load_img(path + '/images/' + id_, color_mode="rgb")
    img = img_to_array(img,data_format='channels_first')
```